# PHP: Referencing static files that is inside a phar archive from html

Tags: php, html, file, static, phar

I tried using phar in my application but there's a slight problem for me. Earlier i did made a web project, put my classes and php files containing html files in a phar, but i couldn't import static files to phar and referenced them from html tags. What i did was this:

- Created a phar archive containing my classes and html codes. i created two stubs, for cli access and operations in cli.php, and for web access, i wrote index.php (this file requires other php files and evidently echoes html codes).

phar build conf of phing build.xml:

```
<pharpackage
    destfile="./target/${phar.file.name}.phar"
    basedir="./"
    webstub="index.php"
    clistub="index.php">
    <fileset refid="pharBuild"/> ...
```

cli.php file is like this:

```
<?php
 if ($argv[1] === "op1") {
   // do something
 ...
```

index.php file is like this:

```
<?php 
if (php_sapi_name() == "cli") {
require_once "cli.php";
} else {
// prepare and print the web page. evidently some HTML tags.
```

- a configuration folder for stuff... you know :)
- assets folder for images,styles and stuff.
- add an index.php file that includes the phar archive. i couldn't run phar archive directly.

So how can i reach my images, styles and js  if i import it to the phar file? I want to put the css/ , js/ and images/ folders inside this phar and without changing the current code too much, when html page needs a image (like `<img src="IMAGE-LOCATION-I-DONT-KNOW">`), it will get it from the file that is inside my phar file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your setup isn't working, but I can access static files through a PHAR just fine. Here's what I've got:

`build.xml`

```
<target name="package">
    <pharpackage basedir="." destfile="./my-project.phar" stub="phar_stub.php" compression="none">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <include name="**/**"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="vendor">
            <include name="**/**"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="public">
            <include name="**/**"/>
        </fileset>
    </pharpackage>
</target>
```

`phar_stub.php`

```
<?php

Phar::mungServer(['REQUEST_URI', 'SCRIPT_NAME']);
Phar::webPhar(null, __DIR__ . "/public/index.php");
__HALT_COMPILER();
```

`src` and `vendor` contain classes and `public` contains an `index.php` (the entry point to the application) as well as a `resources` folder with css and js.

Once deployed I can access my application via: http://localhost/my-project.phar/public/index.php/some/route

And the static resources can be accessed via: http://localhost/my-project.phar/public/resource/app.css

One thing I definitely struggled with was having "compression='gzip'", which would deliver a compressed version to the browser, but the browser couldn't figure out how to decompress it. I turned off compression instead of playing around with it too much. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you! stub file was the problem for me. I changed it and it worked. Gotta search about this mungServer stuff... Have a nice day!